# Problem with hiding button in panel in Cpanel dialog mql4

Tags: c++, class, mql4, metatrader4

I made this simple panel as below it have one label and two button when I press one of them the other will be hidden but when i click at place of hidden button it still work I don't know why
I used "cPanel" Dialog from include library and button(in Control Folder)
I  used .Hide() command but it still actionable
also tried the .Disable and Deactivate features but not working at all
code from mqh file:

```
#define INDENT_LEFT_ScrollQ                         (11)      // indent from left (with allowance for border width)(for Scroll Bar Only)
#define INDENT_LEFTQ                         (11)      // indent from left (with allowance for border width)
#define INDENT_TOPQ                          (11)      // indent from top (with allowance for border width)
#define INDENT_RIGHTQ                        (11)      // indent from right (with allowance for border width)
#define INDENT_BOTTOMQ                       (11)      // indent from bottom (with allowance for border width)
#define CONTROLS_GAP_XQ                      (80)      // gap by X coordinate
#define CONTROLS_GAP_YQ                      (40)      // gap by Y coordinate
//--- for buttons
#define BUTTON_WIDTHQ                        (60)     // size by X coordinate
#define BUTTON_HEIGHTQ                       (20)      // size by Y coordinate
//--- for the indication area

#define EDIT_HEIGHTQ                         (20)      // size by Y coordinate
#define GROUP_WIDTHQ                         (150)     // size by X coordinate
#define LIST_HEIGHTQ                         (379)     // size by Y coordinate
#define RADIO_HEIGHTQ                        (56)      // size by Y coordinate
#define CHECK_HEIGHTQ                        (93)      // size by Y coordinate
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Class CPanelDialog                                               |
//| Usage: main dialog of the SimplePanel application                |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
class CPanelDialogQ : public CAppDialog
  {
private:
 
   CLabel            m_Label_Q_text;


   CButton           m_button_Yes;
      CButton           m_button_No;




   //****************************************************


public:
                     CPanelDialogQ(void);
                    ~CPanelDialogQ(void);
   //--- create
   virtual bool      CreateQ(const long chart,const string name,const int subwin,const int x1,const int y1,const int x2,const int y2,string QText);
   //--- chart event handler
   virtual bool      OnEvent(const int id,const long &lparam,const double &dparam,const string &sparam);

protected:

   //--- create dependent controls

   bool              CreateLabel_Q_text(string QT);

   bool              CreateButton_Yes(void);
   bool              CreateButton_No(void);

   void              OnClick_button_Yes(void);
   void              OnClick_button_No(void);


  };
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Event Handling                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
EVENT_MAP_BEGIN(CPanelDialogQ)

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
ON_EVENT(ON_CLICK,m_button_Yes,OnClick_button_Yes)
ON_EVENT(ON_CLICK,m_button_No,OnClick_button_No)

EVENT_MAP_END(CAppDialog)
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Constructor                                                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
CPanelDialogQ::CPanelDialogQ(void)
  {
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Destructor                                                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
CPanelDialogQ::~CPanelDialogQ(void)
  {
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Create                                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool CPanelDialogQ::CreateQ(const long chart,const string name,const int subwin,const int x1,const int y1,const int x2,const int y2,string QText)
  {
   if(!CAppDialog::Create(chart,name,subwin,x1,y1,x2,y2))
      return(false);
//--- create dependent controls

   if(!CreateLabel_Q_text( QText))
      return(false);
   if(!CreateButton_Yes())
      return(false);
  if(!CreateButton_No())
      return(false);

//--- succeed
   return(true);
  }


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool CPanelDialogQ::CreateLabel_Q_text(string QT)
  {
//--- coordinates
   int x1=INDENT_LEFTQ;
   int y1=INDENT_TOPQ;
   int x2=ClientAreaWidth()-(INDENT_RIGHTQ+BUTTON_WIDTHQ+CONTROLS_GAP_XQ);
   int y2=y1+EDIT_HEIGHTQ;

//--- create
   if(!m_Label_Q_text.Create(m_chart_id,"QT",m_subwin,x1,y1,x2,y2))
      return(false);
   if(!m_Label_Q_text.Text(QT))
      return(false);
   if(!m_Label_Q_text.FontSize(12))
      return(false);
   if(!m_Label_Q_text.Color(clrBlack))
      return(false);
   if(!m_Label_Q_text.ColorBorder(clrBlack))
      return(false);
   if(!m_Label_Q_text.ColorBackground(clrBlack))
      return(false);
// if(!m_edit.ReadOnly(true))
//    return(false);
   if(!Add(m_Label_Q_text))
      return(false);

   m_Label_Q_text.Alignment(WND_ALIGN_WIDTH,INDENT_LEFTQ,0,INDENT_RIGHTQ+BUTTON_WIDTHQ+CONTROLS_GAP_XQ,0);
//--- succeed
   return(true);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool CPanelDialogQ::CreateButton_Yes(void)
  {
//--- coordinates
   int x1=INDENT_LEFTQ;
   int y1=INDENT_TOPQ+CONTROLS_GAP_YQ;
   int x2=x1+BUTTON_WIDTHQ;
   int y2=y1+BUTTON_HEIGHTQ;
//--- create
   if(!m_button_Yes.Create(m_chart_id,m_name+"Yes",m_subwin,x1,y1,x2,y2))
      return(false);
   if(!m_button_Yes.Text("Yes"))
      return(false);
   if(!Add(m_button_Yes))
      return(false);
   m_button_Yes.Alignment(WND_ALIGN_RIGHT,0,0,INDENT_RIGHTQ+CONTROLS_GAP_XQ*2,0);
//--- succeed
   return(true);
  }





//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool CPanelDialogQ::CreateButton_No(void)
  {
//--- coordinates
   int x1=INDENT_LEFTQ+CONTROLS_GAP_XQ;
   int y1=INDENT_TOPQ+CONTROLS_GAP_YQ;
   int x2=x1+BUTTON_WIDTHQ;
   int y2=y1+BUTTON_HEIGHTQ;
//--- create
   if(!m_button_No.Create(m_chart_id,m_name+"NO",m_subwin,x1,y1,x2,y2))
      return(false);
   if(!m_button_No.Text("NO"))
      return(false);
   if(!Add(m_button_No))
      return(false);
   m_button_No.Alignment(WND_ALIGN_RIGHT,0,0,INDENT_RIGHTQ+CONTROLS_GAP_XQ*1,0);
//--- succeed
   return(true);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CPanelDialogQ::OnClick_button_Yes(void)
  {

   Print("OnClick_button_Yes", "Last Error: ",GetLastError());

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CPanelDialogQ::OnClick_button_No(void)
  {

   Print("OnClick_button_No", "Last Error: ",GetLastError());

m_button_Yes.Hide();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and the indicator code:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                             Indicator_Q_Test.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window
#include  <WinUser32.mqh>
#include "PanelDialog_Q.mqh"
CPanelDialogQ ExtDialog;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//--- indicator buffers mapping

   if(!ExtDialog.CreateQ(0,"Question",0,100,100,400,230,"This the test Question?"))
      return(INIT_FAILED);
//--- run application
   if(!ExtDialog.Run())
      return(INIT_FAILED);
 
      
     // int k=0;
   //    k=MessageBoxW(WindowHandle(Symbol(),Period()),"Are you sure to Disable Total ?","Question",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_TOPMOST);
    //   Print("k: ",k);
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {
//---
   
//--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
   return(rates_total);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Timer function                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer()
  {
//---
   
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| ChartEvent function                                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnChartEvent(const int id,
                  const long &lparam,
                  const double &dparam,
                  const string &sparam)
  {
//---
      ExtDialog.ChartEvent(id,lparam,dparam,sparam);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: As usual it helps to see some code. It's unlikely that anyone can tell you what is wrong with your code unless they can see it.

Comment: yes , i added it now

Comment: According to documentation `m_button_Yes.Disable();` is what you are supposed to do. You can test the return value from that function, it's supposed to return `true` when successful, so it might be worth doing that. Also might be worth checking the value of `m_button_Yes.IsEnabled();`

Comment: I added Disable and it returns true i also check Is Enable after and it returns false, but still after hide if I click in that area it still do that On click function

Comment: That's strange. I'm afraid this API is not something I know a lot about, so I have no explanation. Maybe you could dig into the source code to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: thanks anyway, I tried more and i found somehow after the button disabled it will enable again if you click in the area of the button ,I think something make it back to a default setting somehow